# pushViewController animation not working for me

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am doing view based app and i have added tableview. Now i have written in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method as below when user clicks on a row then navigate to "learncourse" nib.

```
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    learncourse *learncourse1 =   [[learncourse alloc] initWithNibName:@"learncourse" bundle:nil];      
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:learncourse1 animated:YES];
    [learncourse1 release];
}
```

But this is not working for me when click on the row.

Comment: Did you set up a navigation controller for your project? And you know that you only do this for the second row in your table, if you click on any other nothing will happen because you don't enter the if statement ...

Comment: what kind of error you received on console?

Comment: Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination. this error i got when i clicks second row

Answer (score 0):

Since you started a view based application, I assume you did not create a navigation controller. In your app delegate,change your

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

to something like this

```
UINavigationController *navcon=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[navcon pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
[viewController release];
[self.window addSubview:navcon.view];
```

So what will happpen is your learncourse instance will be pushed onto navcon when you click on the second row in your table view.

Comment: what is learncourse? please explain what is happening when you enter the above code?

Comment: when i run this code..it will be splashscreen displaying then terminating app .

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the 'if' statement and see if it works that way. The push statement seems fine, maybe the problem is with your row/section indexing.

Answer (score -1):

i think problem in this line 
check this line use this code

```
learncourse *learncourse1 =   [[learncourse alloc] initWithNibName:@"learncourse" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: you can pass bundle value nil, there is no compulsion to pass [NSBundle mainBundle]